# Reset method not working on meteor object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm following this angular-meteor tutorial http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/bind-one-object

I'm not sure what I have wrong but here's the code:

```
angular.module('socially').controller('PartyDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){
    $scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false);

    $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.party.save().then(function(numberOfDocs){
      console.log('save success doc affected ', numberOfDocs);
    }, function(error){
      console.log('save error', error);
    });
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.party.reset();
  };
});
```

here's the html:

```
Here you will see the details of party:

<input type="text" ng-model="party.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="party.description">

<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
<button ng-click="reset()">Reset form</button>
<button ui-sref="parties">Cancel</button>
```

the save button is saving the object normally but the reset action doesn't do anything, no errors or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.party.reset();` does not clear the form, instead it just resets the current value of the object to the one stored in the database. For instance, if you modify the attributes of a `Parties` document and you call the reset function, the client version of the Meteor object will be reset to the server version.

Read more about [$meteor.object](http://angular-meteor.com/api/meteorObject).